# Cannot get rid of Mysql / PhPMyAdmin on a Raspberry running Debian-12

Tags: software-installation, apache2, mysql, phpmyadmin

After installing MySQL on my Raspberry web-server, I realized I'd made a few errors in setting up its passwrds. Unable to correct these, I decided to remove MySQL and start over.
Bad move.
I've since been unable to remove it completely, and even a removal of Phpmyadmin has been unsuccessful. I have followed much advice here and on other websites, all of it to no avail.
It's the usual

```
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'mysql-common' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
(Reading database ... 172423 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing phpmyadmin (4:5.2.1+dfsg-1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/phpmyadmin.postrm: 144: .: cannot open /usr/share/dbconfig-common/internal/mysql: No such file
dpkg: error processing package phpmyadmin (--remove):
 installed phpmyadmin package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 2
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
```

All that remains now is to remove PHP-8 and if this is insufficient, I'll remove Apache2 (having backed up the /etc/apache2/ confs and the /var/www details).
And if I still have **problems with this accursed MySQL,** I guess I shall reinstall the Raspberry Bookworm.

Does anyone have a simpler solution?

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and [*official* flavors of Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/desktop/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.